# Error MongoDb Cannot implicty convert type C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to make a general "GET" in MONGODB.
But it does not convert error:

Cannot implicty convert type

[image]

> My Service

```
namespace AdmissionAnonymousForm.Infrascructure.Services
{
    public class BankService: IBankService
    {
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Bank> _bank;

    public BankService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("AdmissionAnonymous"));
        var database = client.GetDatabase("AdmissionAnonymous");
        _bank = database.GetCollection<Bank>("Bank");
    }

    public  Task<Bank> Get()
    {
        return   _bank.Find(bank => true).ToListAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

> My Model

```
namespace AdmissionAnonymousForm.Infrascructure.Services.Core
{
    public interface IBankService
    {
        Task<Bank> Get();
        Task<Bank> Get(Guid id);
        Task<Bank> Post(Bank bank);
        void Update(Guid id, Bank addressIn);
        void Delete(Guid id);
    }
}
```

Comment: you're returning a `List<Bank>` in `Get` but the return type is `Task<Bank>`?

Comment: When you get this kind of error message, always check the two types carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the return type of `Get` method should be `Task<List<Bank>>`

```
public  Task<List<Bank>> Get()
{
    return _bank.Find(bank => true).ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a list and is expecting a single object of Bank